# snapper -c home create-config /home

Tags: opensuse, snapshot, snapper

After installation of openSUSE,  `snapper -c home create-config /home` says "Creating config failed (creating btrfs subvolume .snapshots failed since it already exists)". I want to have Snapper work with these snapshots and contents created by snapper before installation. Googling how and many say I should manually rebuild the .snapshots, so the meaning of rebuild is removing and creating the subvolumes? So all data will lost. Can my Snapper work with these snapshots without lossing data?

Comment: There is no much information on the format of SNAPPER_CONFIGS="", so I guess it's adding `SNAPPER_CONFIGS="home"` to a new line of /etc/sysconfig/snapper, until someone discussing `SNAPPER_CONFIGS="root home"`, which is right. Then manually create home file to /etc/snapper/config/, I don't need to restart, no data lost.